# Extract and count years from data in R

Tags: r, date, statistics, grouping

I was trying to extract and count the years from data.

I changed the data format as:

```
a$time = strptime(a$time, format="%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
```

and now I want to know how many times of a year appears. For example, how many data are from year 2008. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't supplied any data, I'm generating a `data.frame` with one column, that contains many different days between 2007 and 2017

```
a <- data.frame(time = seq(as.POSIXct("2007-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2017-01-01"), by = 60 * 60))
```

I am using `seq()` to generate a sequence of dates, from `2007-01-01` to `2017-01-01`, with a difference between each date of 60*60 seconds (i.e, 1 hour)

Looking at the head of the data.frame, here we have dates and times, separated by 1 hour (as expected).

```
head(a)
#                  time
# 1 2007-01-01 00:00:00
# 2 2007-01-01 01:00:00
# 3 2007-01-01 02:00:00
# 4 2007-01-01 03:00:00
# 5 2007-01-01 04:00:00
# 6 2007-01-01 05:00:00
```

---

You are interested in knowing how many times each year appears in the data.frame. Therefore, we can format the date by just the year (`"%Y"`)

For example,

```
head(format(a$time, format = "%Y"))   ## gives the 'head' of the data, formatted in years.
## [1] "2007" "2007" "2007" "2007" "2007" "2007"
```

From the help file `?table`

> table uses the cross-classifying factors to build a contingency table of the counts at each combination of factor levels.

i.e. it counts the number of occurrences of each value. So we can use `table()` to count the number of times each year occurs.

Breaking this down into stages:

```
t <- format(a$time, format = "%Y")
head(t)
[1] "2007" "2007" "2007" "2007" "2007" "2007"
```

So to get the number of times each year occurs in the data, we can use `table(t)`.

```
table(t)
# 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 
# 8760 8784 8760 8760 8760 8784 8760 8760 8760 8784    1
```

And if you wanted this stored as a data.frame, you would use

```
    df_t <- as.data.frame(table(t))
#      t Freq
# 1 2007 8760
# 2 2008 8784
# 3 2009 8760
# 4 2010 8760
# 5 2011 8760
# 6 2012 8784
```

To find the amount of data collected for a given year, you just subset this data.frame for that year.

```
df_t[df_t$t == 2008,]
# t Freq
# 2 2008 8784
```

So we have 8784 observations for 2008.

Comment: I am new to R so I am sorry that I do not understand it. The data is like consists of many different days from different years, and I just want to know how many data were collected in this year. Would you please explain it to me ? Thanks

Comment: @RMghost - I've added more detail. does this help?

Answer (score 0):

to pull out just the 4 digit years, only ask for the years out of your time, like so:

```
a$years = format(a$time, format="%Y")
```

Then you can tally these up most simply in dplyr. The entire chunk of code to pull out the years only and filter for just a certain year and then count those up would be:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% transmute(years = format(time, format="%Y")) %>% filter(years == "2008") %>% tally
```

> for further information, Hadley's dplyr Vignette is a great place to begin: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html